# Must using Stack Overflow tags be approved by the name rights holders?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229868) related to iText. One of the rights holders (as I suppose) removed the [itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext) tag.

The [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229868#comment50459045_31229868) on my question, by [Bruno Lowagie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622493/bruno-lowagie), was this:

> I have removed the iText tag because: XDocReport is NOT endorsed by iText Group. You are using iText 4.2 which is a version that is NOT officially released by iText Group. The fact that my name (lowagie) is in the package names doesn't mean that I am responsible for that version. God only really knows what's inside iText 4.2. As explained in the legal section of [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://samples.leanpub.com/itext_so-sample.pdf), there are legal issues with all iText versions before iText 5. Please stop using them.

I left [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229868comment50459174_31229868) in response:

> @Bruno Lowagie I am afraid I can't agree with you. Of course if you have property rights to itext you can (and you did) change the licence. But I have all the rights to use the previous versions what I do. This is the first. Secondly we are not talking here about right - here - at stackoverflow and about your personal rights. I just use the tags of SO and I have all the rights to do it. That's why event if you don't want to see itext tag - this is your personal wishes and of course there are nothing for me. That's why I draw the attention of moderators.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IText):

> As of version 5.0.0 (released Dec 7, 2009) iText is distributed under
>   the Affero General Public License version 3. Previous versions of
>   iText (Java up to 4.2.1 and C# up to 4.1.6) were distributed under the
>   Mozilla Public License or the LGPL. iText is also available through a
>   proprietary license, distributed by iText Software Corp. iText® is a
>   registered trademark by iText Group NV.

Who is right?

Comment: Wikipedia was wrong. I've updated it. As explained in [the changelog for iText 5](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/50), we jumped from version 2.1.7 to 5.0.0 with iText (Java) in order to sync the version numbers with iTextSharp (C#). iTextSharp was at version 4 while iText was still at version 2. You may find iText 4 in the wild by people calling themselves ymasory or weiyeh, but in no way are those people affiliated to iText Group. There has never been an official version of iText 3 or 4. If Wikipedia claims otherwise, then Wikipedia is wrong.

Comment: Think about this: iText 2.1.7 was released on July 7, 2009. iText 5.0.0 was released on December 7, 2009. That would mean that in a time span of 5 months, we would have had iText 3 and 4. While that's not impossible, it's highly unlikely. I have done the migration. I have also done the [legal work](http://www.slideshare.net/blowagie/startup-legal-and-ip), contacting the core contributors to approve the license change between iText 2 and iText 5. It's ridiculous that people down vote answers about legal issues because they don't like the answer rather than because the answer is incorrect.

Comment: There seems to be a conflation of the letter of the law and spirit of the law. At heart I can understand why @BrunoLowagie would want to protect his work; however, this is not the case. While it may not be a supported version and comes with heavy disclaimers it still bears the name and so it should be tagged appropriately. Anything else is just a misguided abuse of the system. If you are so bent against it why not leave the tag (allowing others to find it) and make note that it is not supported (allowing others to see it). You have an opportunity to turn this in your favor with a site like SO

Comment: It appears that while v2.1.7 was released as LGPL, the real issue is that they had no right to release it with that license. So anyone using that source is using it under invalid legal protections. But while it may or may not cause some ongoing legal issues for the iText company, any use of that illegally licensed software IS a problem for the users. Bruno is being nice trying to get those versions expunged, but none of these issues should impact this site legally any further than it would impact Wikipedia to have a few paragraphs about those versions and their legal issues.

Comment: That's not the first time [Bruno Lowagie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1622493/bruno-lowagie) fails to understand SO rules, see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/a/23741982/870604. Your usage of the `iText` tag is fine.

Comment: Yes @ken2k I am so ignorant about how to understand SO rules and how to answer question on SO that I could barely write a 500-page book about it: [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) :D

Comment: @BrunoLowagie 29k rep and you still don't understand you can't edit and overwrite someone else's answer with your own answer? Well, at least you're good at advertising...

Comment: @ken2k Nonsense! I removed the iText tag from the XDocReport question because it's an XDocReport question, not an iText question. Adding the iText tag doesn't add value to the question. I overwrote an answer **once** because it contained some flagrant mistakes. Down-voting the wrong answer, nor flagging it resulted in the removal of the answer. At least at Wikipedia, the sources are checked when a page contains errors and the expert on the matter corrects them.

Comment: @ken2k For instance: in the question above, Wikipedia is quoted. However, the quote no longer corresponds with the reality: the error on Wikipedia was fixed. Are you saying that nobody can overwrite that question that now has the wrong information?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I was specifically referring to [these previous edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23741982/revisions) and the fact your answer about that was a link to your book...
Now for the topic of this meta question, it's not wikipedia here, if someone makes some mistake in a question/answer, comment first, don't overwrite it with your own stuff. You can't change the meaning of an answer by editing it. Add your own instead, if you think it better answers the question.

Comment: @ken2k So, because of *the one time* I edited an answer, you are ignoring the 1.300+ useful answer I posted on SO. Does that sound fair to you?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I'm not ignoring anything (what makes you think that?), 29k rep doesn't come out of nowhere. I'm basically saying SO is not a place where you can overwrite someone else's answer with your own, nor advertise your work.

Comment: @ken2k And I say it happened once and it was more than a year ago. Why are you still complaining about it. The problem was fixed and it never happened again.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie SO 101: (1) Post owners own their posts, and factual corrections are either made with their consent or in comments and separate posts. You've been told this multiple times, but seem unwilling to learn, judging by your comments, so I think it's not wrong of ken to bring up the history. (2) Meta threads like this are for discussions of community policy, not adjudicating factual claims. The issue here is whether we, the SO community, have to deal with your ilk (who wave cease-and-desists around and manipulate tags for brand management) in a special way.

Comment: @Bruno: _"it never happened again"_ Yet, here we are. Your behaviour _hasn't_ improved.

Comment: @ZX9 This morning there was a question wrongfully tagged "pdfbox". Due to the hatred exposed against me, I didn't dare removing it: see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256810/compress-pdf-with-large-images-in-android#comment50519723_31256810). Eventually, the OP removed the tag himself. Is this the goal: creating a situation where nobody fixes errors? Some people are so opinionated that they forbid even the most reasonable things. Why don't they spend their energy on [solving the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229868/xdocreport-converting-odt-to-pdf-with-osgi)?

Comment: Does anyone else think it's funny @BrunoLowagie is threatening SO users with C&D letters but also sells a book of compiled SO questions concerning his iText library?

Comment: @IanAuld The book is available for free through the web site.

Comment: The minimum of 1.99 > 0

Comment: @IanAuld That's on LeanPub. On the [iText web site](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html), it's free.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie there are plenty of examples where hi-rep users remove tags from questions, for instance removing wrong `C++` tag and replacing it with `C` tag and that's perfectly fine. The issue is that you deleted the tag not because the question was not about that `tag`, but rather because you don't want people to talk about that tag. If a product is obsolete or not supported anymore, that doesn't mean that it is wrong to talk and have questions about that product. That's what a tag is: it identifies what the question is about. And questions can be about anything within the scope of the site

Comment: @bolov that tag is used as a KPI. The more questions tagged as iText, the higher the score. It is against my interest to remove that tag, but I removed it anyway, because I don't consider the question as an iText question and I want to keep the KPI score clean. If I wanted to increase the score, it would be in my interest to tag as many questions as possible as iText. I don't do that because that wouldn't be honest.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie if you consider that the question is not about `iText`, then that is a valid reason to want to delete the tag. However from all the talk here (including your comments) I got the sense that you deleted the tag because of the old version and you invoked legal arguments in your motivation. In other words you deleted the tag because you feel people shouldn't use `iText` version before 4.

Comment: @bolov Me mentioning that iText® is a Trademark owned by iText Group was the result of a discussion that has been removed by the moderators, but yes, it is in the interest of the employers of the developers that their developers don't introduce old or unofficial versions of iText in their codebase. That's one of the reasons why I was asked to be a mentor at the Founder Institute: I teach a "Startup Legal and IP" class. If developers don't want to learn, so be it. I'll continue teaching anyway.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie You might consider making a separate meta question where you can discuss your tagging proclivities with your fellow experts in the itext tag and SO norms (these folks: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/itext/topusers ). Such tag-specific discussions are common on meta (e.g., in my corner of SO we have "Retag R questions misstaged with [tag:dataframes]"). This question -- the one we're commenting on -- really isn't about your tagging decision so much as whether the rest of us should respect it simply because you are a rights-holder.

Comment: This question has **exactly one** downvote.

Comment: @bolov: Most of the users removing the [tag:c++] tag and replacing it with [tag:c] are wrong to do so.  Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281197 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281384 and my favorite, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430

Comment: @AleksandrM Streisand effect. You're here commenting on it... I'm here commenting on it... Neither of which is insightful or helps.... but here we are doing it. Two downvotes now... I have never seen a bigger mountain made out of a molehill

Comment: It seems @BrunoLowagie has been [at this for a while](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515210/what-is-the-difference-between-lowagie-and-itext/13515403#comment37897969_23741982). Using StackOverflow (and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:IText)) as a means to collect money is generally looked poorly upon. :)

Comment: @Qix I have answered [more than 1300 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1622493/bruno-lowagie?tab=answers) on StackOverflow. If that's looked poorly upon, then I should probably look for another platform...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie and the vast majority of them include links to your book, talk about your "name" or your "brand", or insult other members of the community for their answers.

Comment: @Qix Do the Math and you'll discover that your allegation is wrong. I have published a selection of answers in the form of a free ebook. Read it and you'll find out that most of the answers solve a specific problem.

Answer (score 206):

This is a legal argument that we (the ordinary folks on teh interwebs) are not sufficiently qualified (or remunerated) to argue.

Having said that...

the trademark "iText" can be no more trademarked than other products that belong to the likes of Microsoft, Apple and Google. Yet we have no issues using those here.

My own opinion is that Bruno is being a little bit Chicken Little about the trademark issue. Owning a trademark doesn't stop people from using it when discussing the product - it just helps prevent people hijacking it commercially.

He also has a second argument whereby he cannot endorse or support a particular version of product. **We don't care about that.** Bruno is not obliged to answer any questions, and what he says should not preclude someone else from answering should they know the answer. He is doing a good thing however by advising you that the version you are using could be rather dodgy.

The tags are a classification mechanism, nothing more. Therefore if you have tagged appropriately for your question, he should not be removing it. If a product ends up being called something different due to a trademark dispute, then a retag can take place.

Comment: Also, if there is an intellectual property issue regarding the use of the `iText` *name* (saying nothing of the `[itext]` *tag*), then maybe editing the tag wiki to include that issue would be more efficient and less hostile than going after individual posts while linking to an external PDF. Just saying.

Comment: People are strange. On the one hand, they seem to respect your work because otherwise they wouldn't be using your software. On the other hand, they completely disrespect you as a person, making [false accusations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229868/xdocreport-converting-odt-to-pdf-with-osgi#comment50460035_31229868), insulting the author who's work they use. Don't such people have any pride? Why are they introducing obsolete and unsupported software into their customers' code base? It's an inconsistency in human behavior I'll probably never understand.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie You are doing a good deed by telling the OP that particular version is not supported in any way. However if it is still available and he insists upon using it, there's not much you can do about it. If someone has an answer for him, great, otherwise he'll be forced to upgrade to a version that works. Note that I've updated my answer a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: I have updated the Wikipedia page that talks about iText 4. We have found forks of iText(Sharp) that are using portions of the AGPL version of the code base. We are consistently trying to remove these forks, but the internet is huge and we don't have control over all repositories created by third parties. Developers should be aware that using such a fork is a risk. You don't want to receive [one of these](https://twitter.com/bruno1970/status/611528507374632960), do you?

Comment: @Bruno, again, we have received the message loud and clear, but this has nothing to do with tagging on Stack Overflow. Using the `[itext]` tag to decorate questions related to that technology is perfectly legitimate, as it does not imply we sell or endorse or profit from the forks you want to remove. Insisting we desist from using the `[itext]` tag on questions you deem related to those forks is fighting against windmills at best, abusive at worst. Stop threatening us with C&D orders that have no grounds here.

Comment: @Bruno, would editing the tag wiki so as to record your view of the status of the iText name be a reasonable compromise? People do read these when they are tagging, and can make a decision as to whether they wish to use it based on a note within.

Comment: Nobody gets to arbitrarily remove tags from SO questions like this and if it doesn't stop then a mod needs to step in.

Comment: @KillianDS: It appears you assume that commercial use must be licensed. This is generally not true. Nominative use in particular is allowed. I.e. I can say that I sell Coca Cola if the product I sell is actually Coca Cola. Trademark law intends to protect the customer from getting an inferior product. Now Bruno Lowagie does have a fair point here: trademark law is exactly meant to prevent not-iText being offered as the iText product. SO is not offering any software whatsoever, which makes Bruno's point a lot weaker.

Comment: Wow, threatening legal action. Good job.

Comment: Wouldn't a successful C&D letter get all related questions deleted and blacklisted, making it a lot harder for people to get help with this library? Is that desirable?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I don't THINK that a C&D will stick on a site like Stack... but yeah, if it does, there is a better chance that we simply are NOT allowed to use this library in tags or questions or answers, thus rendering his library harder to support, and less useful over time.

Comment: @MSalters: Excuse me for throwing my three cents here despite not tracking it from the start. I got the feeling that the hassle here is about an old version of a library called "iText", which has evolved/improved and its ownership/license has changed, right?. If I read it well, then how does the trademarking would stop people from calling the **already existing, old product** by its **actual original name**?

Comment: @MSalters: I' writing to you not to argue, but to ask you to continue your thought about `trademark law is exactly meant to prevent not-iText being offered as the iText product`. I understand that now the **current** much better versions are sold under `iText` name, but that still doesn't change the fact that old products were issued under the same name.. If I have bought an Atari computer from '80/'90s, that's still Atari as a product, even though it's moved under JTS/Hasbro/EISA/Infogrames/etc now. Noone got into my house and relabel it.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Your remarks are why I added that last sentence: SO can freely talk about the older versions. TM law is quite limited in scope; it is generally trumped by the right to Free Speech. TM law can only work because commercial speech is less free.

Comment: Just pointing out that the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IText) for iText is a giant advertisement. Wikipedia has three warnings about it. This guy cares more about fame and money than contributing honestly to a community such as SO.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I took the liberty of making a [few improvements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IText) to the Wikipedia page. Hopefully some of those pesky warnings about using Wikipedia as an advertising medium go away now.

Comment: @Qix Thanks! I try not to update the Wikipedia page, because it's not encouraged for project owners to update the page about their own project. Impartial updates (as long as they are correct) are welcomed.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie It's generally not encouraged because project owners usually use it as a billboard instead of a place to post factual information :)

Answer (score 48):

Ignoring all issues about whether he's allowed to do it or not, it seems to me that if Bruno wants to warn people not to use the rogue 4.x versions of iText, he would be better off leaving the tag in place on the question anyway.

His aim is to spread his message to as many people who are using it as possible. Removing the tag means that people who need his advice won't find the question, and thus won't get to read his warning comments.

All he really needs to do is post a comment on the question briefly explaining the issue (and linking to his fuller explaination elsewhere if necessary).

Comment: Not just a comment, I'd suggest answering the question with the explanation to the right path to go. It would be much more clarifying (and less rude) to OP and future visitors if he provided such nice guidance.

Answer (score 12):

It is **not** appropriate for someone with a financial stake in the matter to try to unilaterally reshape the use of a tag.

Appropriate methods are either (a) posting here on Meta to gain community consensus, or (b) pursuing legal action alleging trademark misuse.