# C vs C++. MariaDB and MySQL: same question different language/fork?

Tags: discussion

I'm just wondering if we have a policy on questions that have the same answer but are for different languages? **C++ is not a superset of C, and C is not a subset of C++** (and, let's ignore that). Take for instance this question,

- [Is it possible to declare two variables of different types in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687392/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop)

I'm using C, not C++. I was wondering the same thing. Should I

- Assume that C99, and C11 do it the same way as C++?
- Re-ask the same question with the C-language?

I highly expect the same question in C would result in the same answer as C++. Moreover, I expect that *someone else* would close it as a duplicate if there wasn't a policy on it thus far?

We see the same thing often emerge with MySQL and MariaDB and hybridization and overlap. Though MariaDB continues to diverge, questions on MariaDB that are similar-enough to MySQL are closed as a duplicate.

In summary,

- Is there a stance on not-duping across languages?
- Do we have a policy on this?

Comment: I'm confused by the close vote here. How does this question "not appear to seek input and discussion from the community"? Is there some background I missed?

Comment: I'm confident that we've discussed the policy at length on Meta.  I'm still looking around for a dupe to it...

Comment: @pnuts I wouldn't blame them, since Excel has the sheets concept too.

Comment: Sorry for my heretic opinion, but C++ is in 99% the superset of C. To compile a C code with a C++ compiler is typically far easier as the differences between different OSes or compilers.

Comment: The question belongs to the SO and I can't see any rationality why we can't migrate it with votes to there.

Comment: @peterh It's already been decided that C++ is not C and should not even share the same tags, perhaps you can voice your opinion here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281384/retagging-c-questions-as-c-without-consulting-asker While neither side is without merit, I've already stated we're putting that conversation behind us for the purpose of this discussion.

Comment: @EvanCarroll The typical problems, the frameworks, and common coding practices are very different, because they focus in the C++ exactly to its improvements (to the C). Thus I agree that from our view (tagging) they are mostly exclusive tags. Some questions are tagged as C++ while they don't use anything of its improvements (compared to C) I don't know if it would be better to re-tag them as C or not.

Comment: If we're not retagging them because they're a different language (which is fine I don't care about that argument), then it seems like the next logical question is to take a position on having the similar questions with the appropriate tags (being different). That's what this question is about. Feel free to provide an opinion on it.

Answer (score 4):

If we decide that these are duplicates because the answers are the same, that opens us up to misinformation. See, it is possible for that duplicate nature to change with time.

Consider the "multiple variables in `for`" question. The answer that is true for C is true for C++... kind of. See, it was certainly the same for many years. But C++17 now allows you to do this: `for(auto [x, y] = something; ...)`. In a strictly rigorous standard language sense, `x` and `y` are not "variables" (yes, really). But from a user perspective, you can mostly treat them as such. And `x` and `y` do not have to be of the same types. Indeed, some people abuse this feature for the purpose of putting multiple "variables" of different types in a `for` statement:

```
for(auto [val1, val2, val3] = std::tuple(1, 4.5f, "some_string"s); ...)
```

So while it may be strictly true that C++ is no more capable of allowing you to declare multiple variables of different types in a `for` statement, for all *useful* purposes, that is no longer the case.

So if we allow these to be duplicates due to similar answers *today*, we need a way to un-duplicate them tomorrow should the answers change. That seems kind of weird to me.

The alternatives are essentially this:

1. Allow the questions for the two separate languages/APIs/etc to be distinct, but make one duplicates of the other.
2. Have people ask questions about all of a related family of languages/APIs. That is, a user would ask if C *or* C++ allows multiple variables of different types.
3. Allow the questions for the two separate languages/APIs/etc to be distinct, but without making them duplicates.

I really don't like #2. In the event of language changes, such questions become Too Broad and thus require the creation of two separate questions. And #3 leads to a lot of replicated answers. The best we can do is probably #1 and hope that people are proactive in unduplicating them should changes occur.

Comment: This is useful to inform that specific question, but can it be abstracted out to say that no C question should be considered a dupe of a C++ question? And **no** MySQL-specific question should be considered a dupe of a MariaDB-question (and vise-versa)

Comment: @EvanCarroll: That's why I'm not saying it's wrong to see them as duplicates. Just that it's odd, since things can change. I've added an evaluation of the available options.

Answer (score 2):

As with any question, what matters is, "Are the differences in the question relevant to the answer?"  If you have that problem, have found that question, and want to know if it solves your problem, *try it*.  See if the solution works.  If it doesn't, explain what you're trying to accomplish, what you tried to do to solve it (linking the question here would be nice, but not mandatory) and explaining why, specifically, it doesn't work for you.  The questions at that point can't be duplicates, because you've *demonstrated* that they aren't, and why.

Comment: But that requires the person asking the question to know the answer to the question. I honestly don't know if C11, or C99 can declare variables of different types in a `for` loop. I assume no but only because of the answer on C++ question, and that's the kicker. Is the question off-topic because of the answer?